# Script that deletes itself by mistake

Tags: batch-file, delete-file

This batch script is supposed to map to PC and rename the files in that folder using the date & time stamp and copy them to another location on a different PC. It should then delete all the files in that source folder except for a file that called "LBBS.log". It all works fine except for the delete part. It isn't deleting anything in the folder and it is actually deleting the batch file itself. When I run it, it copies over fine but then it deletes itself. Can someone please tell me what I need to change for this to work. What am I missing? Its on a windows 7 environment. Thanks in advance.

```
net use x: \\MTLLBBS023\C$
set "stamp=%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10,4%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%"
set "source=MTLLBBS023"
xcopy /S /E /I x:\logs E:\Data\Logs\MTLLBBS023\%source%-%stamp%.*
cd x:\Logs
for %%i in (*) do if not %%i == LBBS.log del %%i
net use x: /delete
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your script and target directories are located on separate drives.

When you `cd` to another directory, the command will fail if you try to move to another drive without using the `/d` option.

Instead of `cd x:\logs`, you should say `cd /d x:\logs` - this will change the drive and directory.

Alternatively, instead of the `net use` and `net use delete` commands, you can simply `pushd \\MTLLBBS023\C$` to go to the network drive (this also automatically creates a temporary network drive) and then `popd` at the end of the script to leave the directory and remove the mapped drive. This way, you don't need to `cd` at all.

Comment: Ty for answering. I haven't been able to test this until now and I'm getting promted at the end of the script. I'm using cd /d x:\logs Based on your suggestion.

After "net use x: /delete" it says: 
"There are open files and /or incomplete directory searches pending on the connection to x:.
Is it OK to continue disconnecting and force them closed? <Y/N> [N}:"

Why is it telling me there are open files when there isn't, and how can I just get it to ignore and close the connection? Thanks so much for your help.